Trying to figure out a Light switch going to a a bathroom exhaust/light, wired a new switch the same way as old on but now it turns on or off both?
I am switching out an old light switch because one of the switches broke off. I replaced it with a new one and wired it up the exact same way but instead of being able to turn off the bathroom exhaust OR light in the single unit.. it now only turns off both and one of the switches does nothing.
The old switch had on the left side and a1 and b1, and on the right  it had two commons. Top left a1 was a black wire and bottom b1 was a red wire. The bottom right common was a black wire. Old one is a Leviton.
The new switch left side has +line for both top and bottom. The right said is unlabeled for both connections. New one is left and.
I tried wiring it the exact same way but get the alternate outcome.

Pictures of the old switch and the new switch, as well as how the old switch was wired before you took it apart, may help you get good answers.

I took some. Not sure how to add em on here?

Maybe this would work.. that's the wall with the three wires.. the top switch is the old one and the bottom is the new one..                                        https://photos.app.goo.gl/qwCeok1z7CJAMnn5A

It looks like the box had 2 switches mounted on it, so how did you actually turn on/ off the two different devices? The old switch might have been a "4-way" instead of a basic switch, since it has 2 commons. You could test this with a continuity tester and see what goes where with the switch in it's two positions.

The pictures can best be added by clicking the Edit link for your question, then click the Mountain icon to add the pictures.

One switch was for the fan and another for the light in the unit. But when I wired up the new switch one does basically nothing while the other flips both the light and exhaust on or off but not either.

Anyone have any thoughts?
